# Python nested for loop replacing index with number

Tags: python, function, loops, for-loop, indexing

I am trying to be able to replace the digit of the array with each index in another array referencing the original string.

it works with replacing single digits but when there are double digits it does not go through the full range and doubles up.

here's is relevant code

```
digit = str(input("digit"))   
                              
count = digit.count("%d")

 
                                                                                                     
def replacechar(string, char):                                                                           
    string = string.replace(char, "Ď")              
    return string                                                                                        
                                                                                                         
                                                                                                         
def charposition(string, char):                                                                          
    position = []  # list to store positions for each 'char' in 'string'                                 
    for n in range(len(string)):                                                                         
        if string[n] == char:                                                                            
            position.append(n)                                                                           
            print(string)                                                                                
    return position
```

the functions above and code below.

```
digit = replacechar(digit, "%d")                                                                         
# replacing cxh                                                                                          
position_index = charposition(digit, 'Ď')                                                                
# creating index range                                                                                   
                                                                                                         
                                                                                                         
num_range = 0                                                                                            
                                                                                                         
for a in range(len(position_index)):                                                                     
    num_range = num_range * 10 + 9                                                                       
                                                                                                         
print(num_range)                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
for i in range(num_range + 1):                                                                           
    x = [int(d) for d in str(i)]                                                                         
                                                                                                         
    if (len(str(num_range))) > 1:                                                                        
        if len(x) == 1:                                                                                  
            x.insert(0, 0)                                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                     
#I have also tried this code which works however the same issue occurs 
    g = 0                                                               
    for p in position_index:                                            
        z = digit.replace(digit[p], x[g].__str__())                     
        print(z)                                                        
        g+=1
```

thanks!

```
sample output (single digit)

digit: test%d test0
test1
test2
test3
test4
test5
test6
test7
test8
test9

sample output (multiple digits)
digit: test%d%d

test88
test00
test99
test11
test00
test11
test11
test11
test22
test11
test33
test11
test44
```

Comment: can you give sample input and output? actual output n expected output

Comment: updated the post added output

Comment: What’s the input like `num_range`?

Comment: Can you update it so that the code you show is runnable?

Comment: Updated the full code and all previous functions thanks guys

Comment: Despite your edit, the code is still not runnable. What is *digit* ?

Comment: updated added ' digit = str(input("digit")) ' it is just a string that will be altered later replacing the %d character

Comment: What would be a typical input value?

Comment: @BrutusForcus any word or characters

Comment: What is the significance of counting the substring "%d"

Comment: @BrutusForcus trying to replace it with all possible number combinations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
from itertools import product

string = input("string: ")
parts = string.split("%d")
num_digits = len(parts) - 1
if num_digits > 0:
    for digits in product("0123456789", repeat=num_digits):
        print(
            "".join(
                part + digit for part, digit in zip(parts, digits)
            ) + parts[-1]
        )
```

Result for `string == 'test%d'`:

```
test0
test1
test2
test3
test4
test5
test6
test7
test8
test9
```

Result for `string == 'test%d%d'`:

```
test00
test01
test02
test03
...
test97
test98
test99
```

**EDIT**: After rethinking about the problem the following approach seems better:

```
from itertools import product

string = input("string: ")
num_digits = string.count("%d")
if num_digits > 0:
    digit_str = string.replace("%d", "{}")
    for digits in product("0123456789", repeat=num_digits):
        print(digit_str.format(*digits))
```

Comment: Wow thankyou @Timus this solution is great and I can definitely implement this into my program!! im going to look more into itertools i didnt know there was a libary for this specific function.

Comment: do you need the ' + parts[-1] ' at the end of the print statement? @Timus

Comment: @Oakzeh I need it in case you have a string like `'test%dX'`. Without the `parts[-1]` the `'X'` would get lost. If the `'%d'`s are always at the end, then there is no need for it.

Comment: Absolute legend @Timus this is exactly what I was looking for, simplified my code so much thankyou!!!

Comment: @Oakzeh I just rethought about your question and added another version, which I actually like better than the first.

Comment: Thankyou @Timus you have been a great help both alternatives are awesome! and defiantly helped me out writing my program

Answer (score 0):

It's really unclear what you try to do.
But the best I can advice it's to look at regex library.

**Find here a solution:**

```py
import re
import logging
from typing import Iterator

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)


def insert_digits(string_input:str)->Iterator[str]:
    """Replace a sequence of %d by numbers

    Args:
        string_input (str): string containing 1 series of %d

    Yields:
        Iterator[str]: yield a string where a series %d is replace by a series of digits with same length
    """
    # Define a pattern: for this example a series of %d (+ at least 1)
    digit_pattern = re.compile(r"((%d)+)")

    # use search to find the first occurence of the pattern in the string
    match_result = re.search(digit_pattern, string_input)

    if match_result:

        start,end=match_result.span()  
        string_begin, string_pattern, string_next=string_input[:start] ,  string_input[start:end+1],  string_input[end+1:]

        
        logging.debug(f"begin:{string_begin}({len(string_begin)}), pattern:{string_pattern}({len(string_pattern)}), next:{string_next}({len(string_next)})")

        nb_digits=int(len(string_pattern)/2)
        for index in range(0,10**nb_digits):
            yield (f"{string_begin}{index:0{nb_digits}}{string_next}")

    else:
        logging.info("No match")


def main()->int:
    """Main function for this module

    Returns:
        [int]: 0 if program runs correctly

    Note:   
        why a main function ?
            - because you might import this module to use the insert digits function
            - it avoid to have variable available in the global scope
            - because some tools will import your module (like sphinx for documentation)
    """
    try:
        for p in insert_digits(string_input = "test%d%d"):
            print(p)
        return 0

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        logging.warning("Execution Aborted manually.")
        return 1
    except Exception as err:
        logging.error("An unhandled exception crashed the application!", err)
        return 1

    

if __name__=="__main__":
    exit(main())
```

Comment: thankyou very much @olibou ! this is also fantastic a lot more complicated then my attempt. I will also try to analyse and implement your solution! cheers :)